# SP 2010 Error handling validation controls

Tags: development

I was looking if it's possible to re-use the Sharepoint validation control used to check the URL name for special characters. I like to use this error validation in my custom application page to create new sites.

I'm looking for the ValidationExpression in fact...

Thanks in advance!

PS. Karine Bosh has written some nice post about validation controls:
http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/sharepoint-validation-controls/

Answer (score 2):

If you look at newsbweb.aspx you'll see that the validation is done in the form submit event rather than by a control

```
var ix = IndexOfIllegalCharInUrlLeafName(stname);
if (ix == -1)
    ix = stname.indexOf("+");
if(ix != -1)
{
    var ch = stname.charAt(ix);
    alert(StBuildParam(L_ContainIllegalChar_Text, L_webfield_TEXT, ch));
    return false;
}
```

The IndexOfIllegalCharInUrlLeafName function is contained in commonvalidation.js which also contains other url utility functions such as UrlContainsIllegalStrings